# How to get the real-time duration from origin to destination in GMaps javascript API

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find the live duration between the 2 endpoints using google maps API key.

I have tried directionsService, but the duration I am getting from the response is ideal(not live data)

Answer (score 0):

The live traffic duration between 2 endpoints can be obtained by DistanceMatrixService API call

```js
var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
service.getDistanceMatrix(
{
 origins: [startLatLong],
 destinations: [endLatLong],
 travelMode: 'DRIVING',
 drivingOptions: {
  departureTime: new Date(Date.now())
 }
}, function(response, status){
 travelDistance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
 travelDuration = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration_in_traffic.text;
 distanceTimeInfo = travelDuration + "(" + travelDistance + ")";
 console.log(distanceTimeInfo);
});
```